# Weed Eater Bump Knob Stuck

Tags: lawn-mower

I have a Stihl FS 36 which I was given. I was using it today and tried to bump the knob to let out some string but none came out. I tried to disassemble the spool to remove what I presume is a tangled mess.

I have one slight problem, the bump knob is not budging. I tried for a while by hand and then I brought out a vice grip and I still couldn't get it to budge.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to screw off the bump knob?

Here is a [forum post](http://www.mytractorforum.com/126-chippers-trimmers-leaf-blowers-vacuums/132228-free-stihl-fs-36-40-trimmer.html#/forumsite/20477/topics/132228?page=1) that has the same spool set up as mine in case anyone wonders exactly what it looks like.

Comment: Just a guess but on some string trimmers the screw is a left-handed thread, so it unscrews clockwise.  Did you check the manual?

Comment: @JimGarrison Most curved-shaft trimmers have a right-hand-threaded knob, while most straight-shafts have left-handed.  It's because the straight-shaft trimmers have a right-angle-bend gear cluster which reverses the spin of the spool.

Comment: Just checked mine Ross is right .+

Comment: The bump knob assembly doesn't last forever.  It may need replacement.  They're sold separately.  How to get a jammed one off -- force.

Comment: There was A LOT of force needed to get it to come off. I needed vice grips and a second pair of hands, but we finally got it. The head needed to be replaced or something. I ended up buying a new straight shaft weed eater.